# How do you write custom config providers in ASP .NET 5?

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core

According to the ASP .NET 5, you can supposedly [write a custom config provider](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#writing-custom-providers) by inheriting from ConfigurationSource.

However, as with many other things, the API seems to have changed and this doesn't seem to work with the RC.

What is the current way to do this?

Comment: I'm just guessing here from looking at the [JsonConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationProvider.cs) that it may have been renamed since that document was created ie *ConfigurationSource -- *ConfigurationProvider. I don't see anything named Source in the [configuration abstractions](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions)

Comment: That seems to be it. Well done sir, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provider has to implement `IConfigurationProvider`. It can also inherit from `ConfigurationProvider` which implements the required interface.

Take a look at the implementation of the current providers:

- [CommandLineConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine/CommandLineConfigurationProvider.cs)
- [EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs)
- [JsonConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationProvider.cs)